# Attempting to run PHPUnit with a configuration XML file results in exception

Tags: phpunit, integration, phpstorm

I'm trying (for quite a while, with help from fellas at the PHP chat room) to succesfully integrate PHPUnit with PhpStorm.

I've set up the `phpunit.xml` file as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
        backupGlobals               = "false"
        backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
        colors                      = "true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
        processIsolation            = "false"
        stopOnFailure               = "false"
        syntaxCheck                 = "false"
        bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Lamed Test Suite">
            <directory>Custom/*</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

And configured PHP storm successfully to read from that file.

The problem is, I get the following error in PhpStorm's console upon running the tests:

```
D:\Websites\php\php.exe C:\fakepath\ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap D:\Websites\htdocs\lamed\tests\boostrap.php --configuration D:\Websites\htdocs\lamed\tests\phpunit.xml
Testing started at 23:51 ...

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Neither "Lamed Test Suite.php" nor "Lamed Test Suite.php" could be opened.' in D:\Websites\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Websites\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(157): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('Lamed Test Suit...', '')
#1 C:\Users\Dor\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php(95): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#2 C:\Users\Dor\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php(434): IDE_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\Websites\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php on line 100

Process finished with exit code 255
```

It's obviously reading that from the `name=` attribute on the `testsuite` element. The question is, **why?**

#### UPDATES

- I am running **Windows Seven x64 SP1 and PHPStorm 4.0.3**. PHPUnit version is **3.6.12**.
- Typing `phpunit -c "D:\Websites\htdocs\lamed\tests\phpunit.xml"` in the CLI actually gives the same results.
- My `Custom` directory is found in the same folder as the `phpunit.xml` file.

I'm baffled. Would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: I'll look at this again later after resetting my brain. Note that I develop on Linux and I just realized you're developing on Windows, though that shouldn't really make a difference.

Comment: @Lusitanian Think again.  I can't run ANY phpunit tests through a configuration file on Windows 7.  I haven't figured this out yet either.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Interesting. I have no Windows box...otherwise I'd test.

Comment: You do not need to configure that. PHPStorm handles it for you, if you need to setup custom XML or bootstrap files, there is an option: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=4825091#4825091

Comment: @hakre: Appears so! Running `phpunit -c "D:\Websites\htdocs\lamed\tests\phpunit.xml"` gave me the same message.

Comment: @hakre: I gave the exact error message, my OS, and my directory structure. What else would you have me add?

Comment: Try running a single test case from the command line. It seems PHPUnit isn't finding your tests. Are they named like `FooTest.php`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drop the `/*` from the `<directory>` element. This element's text content should point to a directory—not a file glob.

```
<directory>Custom</directory>
```

See the [PHPUnit configuration documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration) for more details on specifying individual files and inclusion patterns.

By default all files ending in `Test.php` (e.g. `UserTest.php`) will be inspected for test cases. If you have a different naming convention you can either switch or add the `suffix` attribute. For example, if you name your tests like `User.test.php` use this:

```
<directory suffix=".test.php">Custom</directory>
```

Comment: That failed. Same exception is thrown. I saw the documentation, even their example XML, when copy/pasted gives me the same error (only it says `Object_Freezer` or `Object/Freezer`).

Comment: @Truth Note that the path is relative to the xml files location. Bzt as David stated the issues comes from phpunit not finding any tests :)

Comment: The phpunit.xml file is sibling to the Custom directory, my test is inside of Custom.

Comment: The file name did not end with `Test`, once I did that it solved the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Since you helped me solve a problem I was head-desking for over 48 hours, I'll award you with a bounty when I can (about 2 days from now). Hold tight :)

Comment: The link is broken, is the following link corresponding to the page you linked in 2012? https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration

Comment: Yup, that's the one. Thanks! That it points to "current" instead of a specific version should keep it from breaking in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you experience is a fallback. It looks like your testsuite is empty (and there is not other additional non-empty testsuite as well).

In that case PHPUnit will to also try to just open something fitting, which does not work. Then you see an error.

- If you have only one empty testsuite, you will see the exception with the name of the testsuite and php added for the try of it.

  ```
  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Neither "Empty-Testuite.php" nor "Empty-Testuite.php" could be opened.'
  ```
- If you have more than one empty testsuite and no working testsuite, you will see and error about the php only, no name added.

  ```
  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Neither ".php" nor ".php" could be opened.'
  ```
- If you have at least a working testsuite but one or more empty testsuites, you will see a short report for each empty testsuite but no error:

  ```
  Empty test suite.
  ```

When I write that this is a fallback it must not mean that this behaviour is intended by PHPUnit. Seeing the error in your case is okay because before you start with tests, you need at least have one running. And before you start with configuring testsuites, the same.

Fix the underlying problem that the test is missing and the error goes away.

The wildcard `*` as mentioned in the other answer - even I'm sure it's correct to not have it - plays no role with your problem as far as I could see.

---

> The information in this answer is based on
>
> - PHPUnit 3.6.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.
> - PHP 5.4.5 by php.net

Comment: But I do have a testcase inside of Custom folder, and it works when I run it directly from CLI. Should it be named anything specific?

Comment: Yes, from [your screenshot in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4853644#4853644) you need to rename the file from `lamed.php` to `lamedTest.php` otherwise PHPUnit will not recognize it and the testsuite is still empty (the first case in the list in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem changed the value for directory to an absolute path instead of a relative path and it worked.
For example I changed 
tests
into
C:\eclipse\Workspace\testweb

Too bad I had to go through a lot of non information and this isn't mentioned in the documentation, neither is it documented how to start the command line interface with a configuration xml file.

phpunit -c tests/all.xml

The php test files have to end with test as well like myTest.php even when you're adding file elements
C:\eclipse\Workspace\testweb\tests\classes\something.php
would not work but 
C:\eclipse\Workspace\testweb\tests\classes\somethingtest.php
would work