# Running PHPUNIT in my terminal error: Neither ".php" nor ".php" could be opened

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, phpunit, phpstorm

When I run PHPUNIT in my terminal there is an error.

[1]devel@manjaro1|0|16:41:28|~ > cd Projects/forum

> [2]devel@manjaro1|0|16:41:34|~/Projects/forum > phpunit
>       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Neither ".php" nor ".php" could be opened. in /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php:100
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(152): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('', '')
>       #1 /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(126): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
>       #2 /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
>       #3 {main}
>         thrown in /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php on line 100
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Neither ".php" nor ".php" could be opened. in /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php:100
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(152): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('', '')
>       #1 /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(126): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
>       #2 /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
>       #3 {main}
>         thrown in /opt/lampp/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php on line 100

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpunit throwing exception when doesn't find file with name of testsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688420/phpunit-throwing-exception-when-doesnt-find-file-with-name-of-testsuite)

Comment: Another possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853974/attempting-to-run-phpunit-with-a-configuration-xml-file-results-in-exception

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your .php file that you want to test.

Like this line if you want to use phpUnit on your file Myclass.php :

```
.....> phpunit MyClass.php
```